# Use local image in React Native Webview

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I was wondering how to use an image inside of a react native `<WebView>`. In the documentation there are a few promising leads such as the `source` prop.

An example of what I'd like to be able to do:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var html = '<html>
      <body>
        <h1>Hi</h1>
      </body>
      <script>
        var image = injectedImage
      </script>
    </html>'

    return (
      <WebView
        html={html}
        source={{uri: './images/button.png'}}
      </WebView>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: Remove that html prop and then try, Does that work? That html makes no sense.

Comment: The html part is working, as it's rendering in the webview. I just can't can't seem to get into the webview.

Comment: If you look at the react native `webview` docs `html` is depricated, use `source`, have you tried the `injectedJavaScript` prop? It sets the JS to be injected when the webpage loads. Just an idea you can create the image and then inject it into the js that way. If it does not offer the functionality you need, you might have to create a custom webview.

Comment: Ok I will give that a shot. Normally in RN I would get an image by using require(), but for injecting JS to the webview how would I go about getting this image? 

`var img = new Image()` `img.src = ??`

Comment: First try to create the image in your `<script></script>` tags using `javascript` inside of your `html` variable and work with it like that. If that does not work try to create it and do some javascript mainipulation within the `injectedJavaScript` and see if you can that way.

Comment: so I have the injectedJavaScript working, which I can use to successfully override the src of the `<img/>` tag in the webview, but I'm not sure how to get images from the local project into the webview.

Comment: can you post your code for that?

Comment: What I ended up doing is just hosting the image on our server and referencing it by its HTTP url. I couldn't find any evidence that a webview has access the the local directory structure so I settled with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and will also host the image on a server and reference it using the url as a workaround.